# Perls system($command) returns other result than command on shell

Tags: perl, bash

I'm trying to fetch a version number from an xml-file on a remote machine. I do this via the Net::SSH::Perl `cmd` function. It looks something like this:

```
my ($version, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("head -11 /some/path/to/the/file.xml | tail -1 | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | xargs");
print Dumper $version;
```

What I'm trying to achieve with that is, to extract the number out of an XML-tag `<version>2.6</version>`

It works perfectly fine, when I use the cmd on a ssh-shell via PuTTy

```
user@remotemachine:~>head -11 /some/path/to/the/file.xml | tail -1 | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | xargs
2.6
user@remotemachine:~>
```

However, Perl prints

```
$VAR1 = '<version>2.6</version>
';
```

Any ideas, why it's not working?

Edit: Obviously it has nothing to do with the Net::SSH::Perl-module, since

```
perl -e "system(\"head -11 /some/path/to/the/file.xml | tail -1 | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | xargs\");"
```

Also prints

`<version>2.6</version>`

Comment: Your command line looks way too complex.  I'm assuming simplifying it would also work around the problem.  Any particular reason you don't simply copy the file over and process it in Perl?  Or try `sed '1,10d;s/<[^>]*>//g:q' /some/path/to/the/file.xml`

Comment: What's with the trailing `xargs`, in particular?  What do you want to accomplish with that?`

Comment: @tripleee The trailing xargs is for cutting off unwanted spaces/tabs/newlines from the output. `echo "   abc   " | xargs` will print `abc` instead of `\ \ \ abc\ \ \ `.

Comment: @tripleee it's really not that complex at all. `head -11` and `tail -1` gives me the eleventh line of the file, which i then modify with a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using double quotes. In double quotes, `\` is special, so only `+` instead of `\+` is passed to `sed`.

You can use the `q()` operator to avoid backslashing the backslash:

```
$ssh->cmd(q(head -11 /some/path/to/the/file.xml | tail -1 | sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | xargs));
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I totally forgot about the double-quotes. Take my +1 and accept :)